# views relationship to field collection field, gives no result for non-administrators

Tags: views, entities

Using a view of field collection items, A relationship to a field collection field works fine for administrators but for other roles like authenticated users or anonymous users, the complete view is not showing, but does render the 'No results behavior' of the view. This sounds very much like a permission issue, but I have checked all permissions many times.

I have the impression that the following issues are about the same thing, but their solution to turn of views data caching, does not work for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/1973090
Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not really a solution, but just for diagnostics, is the problem fixed by selecting _Disable SQL rewriting_?

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right Any, the problem is 'fixed' by selecting Disable SQL rewriting. It apparently is a permission issue, but I can't see what causes this. I don't want to disable SQL rewriting permanently on this view.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the permissions?

Comment: Yes J.Reynolds, I did rebuild permissions but that did not make a change.

Comment: I'd suggest tracing through the `drupal_alter()` in `SelectQuery::preExecute()` to see which module's the culprit. What kind of entity is the field collection attached to? Do you have any other access control modules installed?